# How to iterate a tHiveInput in a Talend Big Data Job?

Tags: java, bigdata, talend

Is there a way to iterate a **tHiveInput** in a **talend big data job**?

Comment: in order to do what? Please elaborate your question

Answer (score 0):

We didn' get much information on your question.

But, Yeah we can iterate tHiveinput.. under row option there is iterate link.. u can leverage that.